# How to show errors in validation form from object of error

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

How can I append text in HTML from choosing according type from object ?
 I try to choose one error from errorText and push it in errors array. And have no idea how to append into HTML.

```
        var btn = document.querySelector('.btn');
btn.addEventListener('click', checkForm);
var select = document.querySelector('.required');
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.form-element');
var errors = [];
var errorText = {
     1 : "The field 'First name' is empty",
     2:  "The field 'Last name' is empty",
     3:  "Pick your date of birth",
     4:  "Pick a country",
     5:  "The field 'E-mail' is empty",
     6:  "Enter your password",
     7:  "The field 'Address' is empty",
     8:  "Enter correct email",
     9:  "Current date is not allowed"
}

function checkForm() {
    for(i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {  
    if (inputs[i].value == "") {
        inputs[i].style.borderColor = 'red';
    }
}
   if(select.selectedIndex=="") {
    errors.push({el :4});
    select.appendChild(errors);
    // select.innerHTML = 'Please, select a country';
    return false;
   } else {
    return true;
   }
}
```

Comment: I've just picked select - option tags as an example

Comment: You should not append the error message to your input as you would need to redo it for each different input. A simpler approach would be to add a  <div> or <span> near you select and html() your error message in it.

Comment: @Bdloul, thank you ! I just wanted to make my code short :)

Comment: Question has absolutely nothing to do with jQuery Validate plugin.   Please be more careful when tagging.  Edited.